# How to update specific field in CodeIgniter update?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using `CodeIgniter` framework for the `easyappointments.org` library. I'm trying to update the field `data` through the id of a row. Actually this is my code for the update:

```
return  $this->db
                ->update('ea_appointments', $appointment)
                ->where('ea_appointments.id', $appointment_id);
```

The problem's that the `update` method need two parameter (table to update, associative array with the fields name column of db). In my above function I pass only the `$appointment_id`, so the variable `$appointment` is empty and doesn't contain any associative array. I want to know how to update only the field `data` to `1`. And remain the other field in the same value condition.
This is the structure of the table:

```
id|book|start|end|notes|hash|unavailable|provider|data
```

**Logic example:**

previous condition row:

```
id => 0
book => example
start => 18/10/2015
end => 19/10/2015 
notes => empty
hash => akdjasldja
unavailable => false
provider => 5
data => 0
```

I pass in the function `$appointment_id` with 0 value. I'm waiting this new result:

```
id => 0
book => example
start => 18/10/2015
end => 19/10/2015 
notes => empty
hash => akdjasldja
unavailable => false
provider => 5
data => 1
```

So the main problem is retrieve first the all field value of the specific row and later update? Or something like this. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In my above function I pass only the $appointment_id, so the variable
>   $appointment is empty and doesn't contain any associative array.

If you simply want to update the column `data` to `1` for appointment_id `0` then pass in an array with `data` for the key and `1` for the value.

```
$appointment_id = 0;
$appointment = array('data' => 1);    
$this->db->where('id', $appointment_id);
$this->db->update('ea_appointments', $appointment);
```

Comment: Oh you're right! Thanks for this is very useful. Just another question and if I want select all the rows of ea_appointments table with the field "data" 0?

Comment: @Dillinger https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: @Dillinger change your `where` to  `->where('data',0)`

Comment: Yeah but is possible set multiple where condition? 'Cause I do the select statement like this: $where_clause = array(
                $where_id => $_POST['resource_id'],};

Comment: @Dillinger yes you can call `where` multiple times or pass in an array with multiple keys. There are examples in the link